# Visual studio Error in adding any references OR installing and updating any packages (loading type library/DLL)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, t4mvc

Visual Studio 2012 RTM

I have a MVC website project and i have some problem with adding some references;

EDIT:

**My Visual Studio has some problems** [(More info in stackoverflow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P576J.jpg)

- I can't add any reference to my projects (even inside new solutions and new projects)
- I can't install any package (by "Packet Manager Console" or Manage NuGet Package)
- I can't update any package (by "Packet Manager Console" or Manage NuGet Package)

For example if i update one of my packages, this will be fail with this installation descriptions:

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4MVCExtensions (≥ 3.5.2)'.
>
> **Successfully installed 'T4MVCExtensions 3.5.2'**. Successfully installed
>
> 'T4MVC 3.5.2'. Updating 'T4MVC' from version '2.10.3' to '3.5.2' in project 'MyWebSite'.
>
> **Successfully removed 'T4MVC 2.10.3'** from MyWebSite.
>
> **Error loading type library/DLL**. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
>
> **Successfully uninstalled**
>
> **'T4MVCExtensions 3.5.2'. Install failed.**
>
> Rolling back...
>
> **Failed to add reference to 'T4MVCExtensions'**.

..........................................[image]...................................

**Edit:**
Or If I add any reference:

.......................[image]

**EDIT:**
I did update the package again when "Process Monitor" software was open and this picture is part of it's log with following filters:

- Selected Activities: **Registry**
- Process Name **is devenv.exe**
- Path **include TypeLib**
- Result **Exclude SUCCESS**

(for better view of the below image right click on it and select "View Image")

[image]

**Key:** HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}\8.0

**Data:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\dte80a.olb

[image]

... and it is the file>>

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: This is pretty unhealthy, it indicates registry problems on your machine.  Run SysInternals' ProcMon and have it active while you do this.  The trace then shows you which key in Typelib is missing.  Add that info to your question.

Comment: @HansPassant, i edited my question with additional picture of "Process Monitor" software. now, is it useful? how can i fix my problem?