# Resharper 7.1 Solution Analysis False Errors

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

In our VS2012 web project we are getting hundreds of errors reported by Resharper, but the software builds and compiles fine.

How do I get resharper to correctly identify the fact that the solution is actually fine.

All the errors are about properties on classes are not found.

I have tried cleaning the solution and forcing Resharper to re-analyze.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper gets confused for many reasons, but some of the times I had issues the solutions I did were:

- like [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds)
- disable Resharper for a set of files: Resharper => Options => Code Inspection =>Settings => Edit Items to Skip
- sometimes is just a bug, make sure is not reported already. Look for example on [this forum thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/185767;jsessionid=3682CDB464B2E194491F95939D352683?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true)

Answer (score 80):

Go to Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> Options -> General and click Clear Caches. Click Cancel and then in the ReSharper options window click Suspend Now and after that click Resume button.

This way you'll clear the corrupt cache and restart the ReSharper.

Comment: After trying several of the recommendations here and elsewhere, this is the one that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: I also had to Unload/Reload the project after this.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else reading this, the suspend/resume is in Visual Studio Options -> ReSharper -> General. 
Or just type "resharper general" into the quick search (ctrl+q).

Answer (score 10):

for me, the problem is fixed by right clicking on the project, 'Unload Project' and reload thereafter.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think this would work but it did! Thanks. For people that don't know, right click on your project in the solution explorer and select "unload project." After unloading the project, right click again and select "reload project."

Comment: This worked for me too. Was not able to get errors to go away using cache/suspend/resume. Had multiple projects in my solution; unloaded projects until errors disappeared, then reloaded projects one by one, which fixed it for me. This time, at least.

Answer (score 0):

For me, inspecting the solution gave me hundreds of errors, including many "cannot find file in search paths". I tried every suggestion out there to fix it and none of them worked. I ended up finding out inspecting the project, instead of the solution, worked perfectly.