# System library not found

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, missing-features

I have a very strange issue that seems to happen more often as time goes on. Basically, whenever I open a project (regardless of which project I open) it appears that VS can't find critical libraries that should always be present (such as System). An example of what I will see when opening a project:

[image]

Mousing over `System` shows: `"Cannot resolve symbol System"`.

For clarity, I am also using Resharper as well as GhostDoc but those are the only two plugins I am using and neither of them seemed to cause this issue when I first installed them way back when.

I've also tried cleaning the project multiple times with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you disable the extensions?

Comment: Make sure they are added as references or at at least System is added in your reference folder. If that doesn't solve it, I would make sure that your computer has those. Did you somehow disallow the System references?

Comment: What .dll files do you see in `References`?  Normally there will be a number of default libraries, but you could be using a template without any default references.

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue w/ ReSharper Ultimate 9.2. I've confirmed the System DLL is there and tried clearing the cache, restarting Visual Studio and restarting the PC. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Following the steps in this answer is the only suggestion that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19772172/1058872

ReSharper Ultimate 9.2 on Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which was fixed by hitting the Clear Caches button in options
[image]