# Lots of "Cannot resolve symbols" in Visual Studio this morning. Also using Resharper. Compiles fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, resharper

This morning, when opening Visual Studio 2012 I see lots of "red code" based around "Cannot resolve symbols". The code compiles and runs fine. I am using Resharper, so not sure if it is an issue with RS?

I did have an issue with my laptop OS over the weekend with a display adapter and windows update corrupting it. I am running windows 7. I did do a restore, but only back a 2 days.

I have closed all files, restarted VS2012 and still not joy.

What do you think might have gone wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

sorted: [ReSharper "can not resolve symbol" even when project builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds)

Comment: Any chance you've updated Resharper to 8.1 and haven't updated a plugin like StyleCop to the latest version?

Comment: Actually still on RS 7.1 :) Thanks for the feedback. Perhaps I need to update for other reasons.

Comment: Agreed, I did find the above link after posting, hence the resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I see this behavior I follow these steps to clear it up... perhaps it will work for you too:

1. Double Click the Red ReSharper icon in the bottom right of Visual
   Studio... this opens up the "Errors in Solution" window.
2. Click the toolbar icon to "Re-analyze Files with Errors" *(the icon looks like a combination of a refresh icon and an exclamation icon)*.
3. Rejoice

p.s. Restarting Visual Studio has done the trick for me as well, but these steps are less invasive.

Comment: I just switched the IntelliSense back to visual studio and its working like a charm, I can't believe I was fighting this for over an hour.  >_> !