# Visual Studio 2013 C# Editor doesn't recognize my class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, editor

Hi  I have 2 classes in a MVC 5 project with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 like the following:

Class #1

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Model
{
    public class OrderLine
    {
          public Product Product {get;set;}
          ....
          ....
    }

}
```

My second file in the same project inside the same folder (Model):

```
namespace Model
{
     public class Product 
     {
         ....
         ....
         //some product class properties
     }
}
```

My problem is that in my first class (`OrderLine`) the `Product` class appears in red and even that the project compiles perfectly I can't access the `Product` properties such as `this.Product.Name` the C# editor cannot find the properties.

As I mentioned the project compiles without problem it is just that the C# editor makes it hard to code because it doesn't recognize the class or properties.

I have try already repair visual studio and repair also the Update 4 without any luck.

Any ideas??

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you have installed Resharper or ProductivityPowerTools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi turns out that I have found the solution for this; it was a Resharper issue which got fixed by following the solution from this post:

Link:
[ReSharper "can not resolve symbol" even when project builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds)

```
Solution:
VS -> Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Suspend button 
Clear Contents of -> AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\SolutionCaches
VS -> Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Resume  button
```

IMPORTANT the folder of version of ReSharper might change according to your latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I pulled in classes from another project in a folder.  Refreshed the files in the project so I could see them, but I didn't specifically add the files to the project.  So they looked included, but it couldn't see them until I specifically included them in the project.