# Why do I always have to build solution on opening in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, projects-and-solutions

My first question on SO, so please be gentle ;-)

As per the title, when I open any solution in Visual Studio 2013, the solution is opening in an unbuilt state, reporting lots of errors etc.  I haven't been able to track anyone else down having the same issue on SO, and have already been through nearly all the VS->Tools->Options and compared with a colleague's settings, but not found a solution so far.  As soon as I press Ctrl+Shift+B the solution builds and all errors go away.

At the moment this isn't such an issue as the solutions and projects are all relatively small, but when we do return to one of our larger projects, the added delay will become annoying.

Thanks
Stuart

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Actually you have to and you should build your program in order to view the latest state. Just wait it to compile. Grab a coffee or beer.

Comment: I would suggest a permissions issue in the file store rather than a Visual Studio issue. Try creating a completely new solution, stored on your local computer, and seeing how that behaves.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The errors are unknown references, as the solution isn't built it doesn't recognise the other classes and projects as far as I can tell.  I have built a very simple local solution to test and so far that seems to be ok, even after checking in and out of TFS.  However, we do normally have the projects stored locally.

Comment: Please do not write answers in the question. The recent edit would be better written as an answer. Your "for now..." comment means the answer is not yet complete. As you get more information you can update the answer. When you are satisfied that your answer, or perhaps someone else's answer, is correct you can accept that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice AdrianHHH, I can't seem to add answers I don't think I have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the sea of red is in fact Resharper complaining and not Visual Studio.

Have tried various fixes as per this link [ReSharper "can not resolve symbol" even when project builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds), but still not resolved.

For now have turned off code inspection in Resharper.