# Automapper.Mapper.CreateMap cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, automapper

I was moving some of my objects that i use automapper for to another project. And suddenly i get the error Cannot Resolve CreateMap in the automapper profile.

[image]

I've been searching for a solution for some hours now but i can't find anything. 
I have reinstalled the automapper nuget but that didn't help

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16458568/3199927)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you dont have any objects called "Mapper" in the current or parent  namespaces.

Try to use full qualified name for Mapper, like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressDTO>();
```

If this does not help, try to clear ReSharper's cache (if you are using R#), then restart visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using latest version you can create map like following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressDTO>();
    //cfg.CreateMap<Customer, RegisterViewModel>();
});
```