# Convert HttpContent into byte[]

Tags: c#, stream, type-conversion, arrays, httpcontext

I am currently working on a c# web API. For a specific call I need to send 2 images using an ajax call to the API, so that the API can save them as varbinary(max) in the database.

1. How do you extract an `Image` or `byte[]` from a `HttpContent` object?
2. How do I do this twice? Once for each image.

-

```
var authToken = $("#AuthToken").val();
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
debugger;
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/obj/Create/", 
    headers: { "Authorization-Token": authToken },
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function () { 
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

-

```
public async Task<int> Create(HttpContent content)
{
    if (!content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new UnsupportedMediaTypeException("MIME Multipart Content is not supported");
    }

    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
{
    throw new UnsupportedMediaTypeException("MIME Multipart Content is not supported");
}

var uploadPath = **whatever**;
if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
}

var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadPath);
await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

return File.ReadAllBytes(provider.FileData[0].LocalFileName);
```

Answer (score 25):

`HttpContent` has a Async method which return ByteArray i.e (Task of ByteArray)

```
 Byte[] byteArray = await Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

You can run the method synchronously

```
Byte[] byteArray = Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

Comment: This returns a nice long byte[], but I have two separate images I need to extract

Comment: Great answer, but avoid using `.Result`, almost always, as it can cause thread locks.

Comment: @VSO Why? Why would it cause thread locks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync`:

```
byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Or, you can read the content with `HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync` and extract to a `byte[]` from there:

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
      await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
      return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @James What .NET version are you on?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: That didn't change anything

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds)

Comment: I wasn't able to get it resolved... but regardless, this doesn't fix the issue where I have two images, or two separate byte[] that I need to extract.

Comment: @JamesMadison Nowhere in your question did you say you'll be receiving a concatenated byte array. You only asked how to read a byte array from a stream.

Comment: First line of the question says I am sending two images

Comment: @James Sending two images to a server by no means says "I have one large buffer". How do you signal the end of the image? You need a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at CopyToAsync(Stream, TransportContext) method exposed by ByteArrayContent Class. [[msdn link]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.bytearraycontent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm looking for an answer with a little more detail, maybe an example