# ReSharper errors - Cannot convert type from mscorlib to type from System.Runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper, portable-class-library

I have a .NET 4.5 class library (containing tests) with a project reference to a portable class library. The PCL targets the following platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

I'm on Visual Studio 2013 Premium with ReSharper 6. At some point recently, I started seeing many, many inline warnings (red squiggly underlines) in the test project indicating the following or similar:

```
Cannot convert source type 'string [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'
    to target type 'string [System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]'
```

There are no build errors or warnings, just the annoying inline errors. If I turn off "Enable code analysis" in ReShaper's settings, they go away, but of course so do many helpful features. This started happening just recently but I can't pinpoint what triggered it. I did upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 recently, not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any tips that might help me pinpoint the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you test your solution with the latest R# version? There were known issues with PCL references, for example [RSRP-430728](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-430728).

Comment: Finally got around to upgrading and after working through a slew of new false-positives with the help of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15713167/62600), everything seems peachy now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ulrichb - this is an issue again (fails for .NET Framework 4.5.2 - works for .NET Framework 4.5). Running JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2 (ReSharper 9.2 in Visual Studio 14.0.24720.0) - I'm not sure if you're a representative of JetBrains -  if not, let me know and I'll remove this comment

Comment: Hi @Rob. Sorry, I'm no JetBrains guy :) I would simply file a new issue in YouTrack, and reproduce it before in R# 10.0.2 or the latest 10.1 EAP (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP). BTW: You can install R# in an VS experimental instance.