# ReSharper cannot resolve symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

I'm currently building an ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1.0) MVC application. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2.

I currently have a 2-tier layer solution which consists of a `Www` (web application) and a `Services` layer. The `Www` has a reference to the `Services` layer.

When ReSharper is **suspended**, the classes within the `Www` layer are able to invoke objects from the `Services` layer, as shown here:

[image]

However, when ReSharper is **enabled**, I get the following message: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Services'`, as shown here:

[image]

What I've tried:

1. Clearing the caches from `Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Ultimate -> Options -> Clear Caches`
2. Remove the `JetBrains` folder from `%APPDATA%`
3. Restarting Visual Studio 2015
4. Reinstalling ReSharper
5. Suspending and resuming ReSharper
6. Adding and removing references
7. Rebuilding the solution

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried VS -> Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Suspend button and Resume again (no need to close the window) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds

Comment: Did you try to rebuild all?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both. I've even tried reinstalling ReSharper.

Comment: What if you try to remove and readd the reference

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: I also have this problem in the same setup. I got 140 errors reported by Resharper but it builds fine. I just created a default Asp.net core website

Comment: I have the same issue. I have tried all that as well as praying :)

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio 2017 I solved in this way:

- Close the solution
- Delete the ".vs" hidden folder
- Reopen the solution and rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Jetbrains is aware of this: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-408661

However, it gave me an idea. I set CopyLocal on the assembly to "true" and now my references resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with v2017.1. Spent some time trying different solutions like clearing cache, suspending and resuming, but no success.

What helped me: I updated to v2017.3.1 (latest on time of writing). So if you facing a problem which you cant fix by simple suspending or clearing cache, consider updating to latest version, probably it was a small bug, and now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me I got to reinstall MSBuild. Then it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems those "EMIT WARNING" defines come from "xkeycheck.h", a standard include file, which wants to check if a standard data type gets overwritten by some define. It seems that somehow ONLY resharper thinks that this is the case, while VisualStudio itself doesn't have any issues. The emitted warning never appears in a compile, only in resharper. I have this issue in exactly one file, and I couldn't yet find the real cause for it. Ayway, adding a "#define _ALLOW_KEYWORD_MACROS" in this file stopped resharper from running amok.