# Ajax POST in MVC returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hey guys I´m having some issues by getting a value to the controller in MVC.

This is my HttpPost at the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void GlobalIsWeekCheck(bool? incomingIsWeek)
    {
        GlobalIsWeek = incomingIsWeek;
    }
```

And this is my script on the view:

```
var incomingIsWeek = false;
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/GlobalIsWeekCheck",
                    data: incomingIsWeek,
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Successfully connected to the server');
                    }, 
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Something went wrong');
                    }
                });
```

Anyone knows why am I getting a null variable on my controller everytime I call this ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data needs to be an object with the correct name so that it can be assigned to the variable.

Adjust like so

```
data: {"incomingIsWeek" : incomingIsWeek}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zach, this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your action lacks `FromBody`, because the input parameter is not a complex object and the action selector try to pick up it parameter from uri.

```
[HttpPost]
public void GlobalIsWeekCheck([FromBody]bool? incomingIsWeek)
{
    GlobalIsWeek = incomingIsWeek;
}
```

Here is the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value
>   from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>   bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>   and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>   a string. (More about type converters later.)
>
> For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message
>   body, using a media-type formatter.

Comment: It looks like ReSharper issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds

Comment: I´ve already fixed the issue by using Zachs fix. I do not know if this will work...indeed seems to be something about Resharper.

Comment: `[FromBody]` is web-api (not mvc as the question has been tagged)