# Why is Rider not resolving references to my installed NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, nuget, rider

I have a .Net Core project and am using the most recent version of Rider installed. I'm pretty new to Rider here (migrating over from using Visual Studio).
One of the projects references the DiDiSoft package

```
(<add key="DidiSoft.OpenSsl" value="https://repo.didisoft.com/repository/openssl/" />)
```

I was originally having issues connecting to the URL as Rider kept prompting me with the UserName/Password dialog. I kept entering the (validated) UserName/Password - and I kept getting the dialog. I was informed me there was an issue with Rider and the work around was to "Use Credentialed Providers" to "None."

I did this and rebooted my system.

Now..., it looks for all intense purposes that the package has been successfully installed.

In the NuGet Console, I see the package listed as installed (in the left panel) and the right panel correctly indicates the project that it was installed to.

How ever the library is not getting correctly resolved (via using statement) in my project source code.

```
using DidX.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using DidX.BouncyCastle.Crypto.EC;
```

> Cannot resolve symbol 'DidX'

I've tried "Restore" and "Forced Restore" of the NuGet package, but I still get the same result.

Other than seeing the unresolved references, I don't see any other error/warning messages.
What steps can I do to resolve this issue? Am I missing something here? Is there a way I can try to do get more information regarding my issue?

Comment: Resharper and Rider have the same problems, so you can try to use some advises from this [ReSharper "Cannot resolve symbol" even when project builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-cannot-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got a similar problem.

You can solve it by add the package to `.csproj` file

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="DidiSoft.Pgp.Trial" Version="1.9.4.24" />

<PackageReference Include="DidiSoft.Pgp.Trial" Version="1.9.4.24" />
```